# Improperly installed valve guides

Tags: machining

I am new at doing cylinder head work and accidentally installed 4 pre spiraled valve guides upside down, can I hammer them back out and reinstall them correctly or do I need to use new ones?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

If you can get them out without damaging them, then it really shouldn't matter. You'll still want to go through the checks to make sure they are good after re-installation.